# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/pubsub/v1/DetachSubscriptionRequest

Tags: java, spring-boot, noclassdeffounderror, google-cloud-pubsub

I am getting the below error:

```
    com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: exception occurred while calling backend method (SystemService.java:373)
        com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: exception occurred while calling backend method (SystemService.java:373)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/pubsub/v1/DetachSubscriptionRequest
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.stub.GrpcPublisherStub.<clinit>(GrpcPublisherStub.java:163)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher.<init>(Publisher.java:187)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher.<init>(Publisher.java:88)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher$Builder.build(Publisher.java:798)
    at com.ca.poc.orchestrator.services.EmailServiceImpl.pushMessage(EmailServiceImpl.java:39)
```

EmailServiceImpl.java:39

```
// Create a publisher instance with default settings bound to the topic
            publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).build();
```

I could not understand what is missing here. I used `google-cloud-pubsub` of version `1.107.0`.

Comment: You are using the latest google-cloud-pubsub version.

I assume you're using Maven. Can you please list the versions of all the packages you're using? We're specifically interested in the versions of proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1 and grpc-google-cloud-pubsub-v1.

Comment: Let's move the discussion to this GitHub issue: https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/issues/280